# AJAX error, not displaying all info

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

    return xmlHttp;
}

function process() {
    if (xmlHttp) {
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "bacon.txt", true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() {

    theD = document.getElementById('theD');

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 1) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 1:server connection established";
    }

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 2) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 2:done";
    }

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 3) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 3:done again";

    }

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status = 200) {

            text = xmlHttp.responseText;
            theD.innerHTML += "Status 4:request done";
            theD.innerHTML += text
        }
    }
}
```

I am only getting `"server connection established"` as output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the listener but merely calling it once.

Replace

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
```

with

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use fiddler here buddy, it seems your request have not fully made it through and your are stuck at `readyState 1` , Which means the connection indeed established but, It cannot proceed to status number 2, which is done, something in interfering.

Use fiddler to monitor your request and see what's going on, then it will be much easier for your to take actions in order to solve your problems.